# Migrated Stored Procedure from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which is migrated to oracle database.

1. In SQL Server I created a temporary tables taking the column names from the table which is comma separated string. Then based upon the column names I created a temporary table.
2. Then I insert rows into the temporary table and query these tables and do the process.
3. Finally Drop the tables.

How can I achieve the same thing in oracle ?

Comment: What is the business problem you are trying to solve?  Why bother with the temporary table?  Why not simply query the source table?

Comment: I am not worrying of temporary tables. I want to say that I have done this in SQL Server. What is the equivalent process in Oracle.

Comment: The equivalent process depends.  What specific problem does introducing the temporary table solve for you in SQL Server?  That will influence the most appropriate Oracle solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you probably need something like a PL/SQL associative array of records (otherwise known as "Index-by" tables).  Fetch the records one by one with a cursor, or use BULK COLLECT to fetch all at once into the array, then process them in memory.